# Timer in c sharp

Tags: c#

How can I copy value of timer to label?I want to assign Timer which are used on frmUser form and want to assign that timer value on another form.I have tried

```
frmUser frm = new frmUser();
label1.Text=frm.timer1.ToString;
```

Comment: Apart from the syntax error (your example doesn't even compile), what exactly would the meaning of the `timer1.ToString()` call? What do you expect it to mean?

Comment: I want to just assign value of timer to label.I tried using Tostring() but it can not convert string to timer value.

Comment: But what do you expect the "value" to mean??? A timer does not have a "value".

Comment: Then how can I pass the value of timer from on form to another?

Comment: Again - what do you mean by the "value" of a timer? What is that?

Comment: Really, what do you mean by value? Inerval in which timer ticks, or ammount of ticks timer already made, or something else? There is no timer value

Comment: yes.value of timer means I am doing fullscreen mode to min mode.fullscreen mode have timer that timer value I want to assign in min mode.for both mode I use form.

Comment: @user1286027 it could be just me, but I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: A "timer" does not have a "fullscreen" or "min" mode. What are you talking about?

Comment: timer is on one form .I want to convert that form full mode to min mode.both form have timer .when I am in full mode timer start but when I switch to min mode timer on that min mode form timer should start from previous value i.e full screen mode value.

Answer (score 5):

Timer has no property for value. You can set label1's text property from timer's `Tick Event`.

Answer (score 3):

```
public int time = 0;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    time++;
}
```

if you want to access time from another form just use

```
Label1.Text = Form1.time.ToString()
```

Basically on each timer tick you increment time by 1 and put it in the label. (Make sure to set the timer interval to 1000 if you want to show seconds

Comment: I dont want this on same form .want to use in another form to assign timer to label.

Comment: the variable time contains the timer value. 
you can make it public and access it from another form

Comment: You need `public static int time` to call it with `Form1.time`

Comment: How to assign the value of timer on one page to the value of timer on another page??

Comment: There is something you should understand. Timer do not have a value. the timer just ticks continuously. if you want to know how many ticks it did refer to my answer. What are you trying to do with the timer on another page?

Comment: I am doing one application in which I use timer on one form which is for fullscreen mode & I want min mode of that form for this I use another form by hiding that form.on the min mode form I want to use timer which runs the next timer ticks of first form means suppose on first form time is 1.20.34 then If i click on min mode then on that form timer start from 1.20.35.

Comment: so can you please tell me how I should use timer on both form..

Comment: In the example I gave you the variable "time" contains the number of seconds elapsed. then from the second form you can access the variable "time" by using Form1.time (Form1 is the name of the form) So from the second form just retreive the "time" from the first form and display it where you want

Answer (score 2):

If you are speaking about `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` Timer, and by value you mean interval of timer, then I guess `timer.Interval` is what you are looking for.

```
label1.Text = frm.timer1.Interval.ToString();
```